# Create email alert after performing multiple tasks

Tags: workflow

I have a list. Many users are having access to this list so it goes through multiple updates in a day.

The requirement is to send a consolidated email alert to the users at the end of the day stating what are the updates done throughout the day.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OOTB Alerts to send a daily notification about any/or specified changes at a specific time each day.

Go to the specific list > select Alerts > Set Alert on this list.

Set up the users you would like to receive this mail, when the alert email should trigger and how often the mail should be sent.

[image]